# How can I modify glossaries?

Tags: glossaries, tipa

I want to create a lexicon which also includes phonetic writing. I don't want to remove any functionality from glossaries, just modify it.

Can I combine tipa with glossaries?
Can I modify glossaries to work with the commented out line?
Is there a better way of doing this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{lk}{LK}{Lebkuchen}
%\newacronym{lk}{LK}{Lebkuchen} {\textipa{\textreve \textupsilon} {gingerbread}}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms
\newpage
Das \gls{lk}
Das \gls{lk}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi asasasasas, what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to have the phpnetic writing the first time the word pops up in text, do you want to put it into the glossary only? Or something completely different?

Comment: I want the glossaries to work as intended but I would also like the phonetic writing to only show up on the acrynym page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this suit your requirements?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\newipaglossary}[5]{\newglossaryentry{#1} {
        first={#3 (#2)},
        name={#2},
        text={#2},
        description={#3 (\textipa{#4}), \textit{englisch: #5}},
}}



\newipaglossary{lk}{LK}{Lebkuchen}{\textreve \textupsilon}{gingerbread}


\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\newpage
Der \gls{lk} schmeckt lecker und kann auch nochmal verwendet werden: \gls{lk}
\end{document}
```

It results in:

[image]

---

### Addition after your question

Of course you can put it into the acronyms list instead of the glossary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\newipaglossary}[5]{\newglossaryentry{#1} {
        type=\acronymtype,
        first={#3 (#2)},
        name={#2},
        text={#2},
        description={#3 (\textipa{#4}), \textit{englisch: #5}},
}}



\newipaglossary{lk}{LK}{Lebkuchen}{\textreve \textupsilon}{gingerbread}


\begin{document}
\printglossaries
Der \gls{lk} schmeckt lecker und kann auch nochmal verwendet werden: \gls{lk}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Yes, is it possible to do this with acrynyms also?

Comment: acronyms are just glossary entries in another list, so yes!

Comment: How would I write that code? I tried changing \newglossaryentry{#1} with \newacronym{#1} and now I get the error message "File ended while scanning use of \ifglsentryexists

Comment: @asasasasas as you can see in the manual, `\newacronym` is a special `\newglossaryentry`. You need to add the type, as I show in my addition.